# Installing certain files with CMake

Tags: svn, cmake

I have a source directory structure:

```
projectSource
|---src
|---include
|---CMakeLists.txt
```

and would like an install directory structure of

```
projectInstall
|---bin
|---include
|---lib
```

My source directory tree is all under version control, so each source folder contains an additional `.svn/` directory. What's the easiest way to install all header files from `projectSource/include` to `projectInstall/include`, while skipping over the `.svn` directories?

I'd like to use something like:

```
set( PROJECT_INCLUDE_DIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include )
include_directories( ${PROJECT_INCLUDE_DIR} )
install(DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_INCLUDE_DIR}/
    DESTINATION "include"
    FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h"
    PERMISSIONS OWNER_READ OWNER_WRITE GROUP_READ WORLD_READ)
```

but even though I'm (attempting to) install only files matching `*.h`, I'm still picking up the `.svn/` directory and contents.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can add `EXCLUDE` keyword to the PATTERN:

```
install(DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_INCLUDE_DIR}/
    DESTINATION "include"
    FILES_MATCHING
    PATTERN "*.h"
    PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE
    PERMISSIONS OWNER_READ OWNER_WRITE GROUP_READ WORLD_READ)
```

Comment: Using `PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE` worked, but my impression of `FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h"` was that only files matching that pattern would be installed. Is that not the case?

Comment: Yes, when `PATTERN` is used without `EXCLUDE`, it installs only matched patterns. You were seeing svn stuff matched because .svn/ dir is containing files with names ending with ".h". So you explicitly need to tell CMake to not look into .svn/ dirs.